# Why org-clock-out and org-toggle-ordered-property have the same key-bind C-c C-x o?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I find that org-clock-out and org-toggle-ordered-property have the same key-bind C-c C-x o.
And also with org-clock-in and org-insert-columns-dblock, the same C-c C-x i.

Sometimes this really messed up. How to make it not get me wrong?

Comment: Perhaps give a concrete example of how you get messed up? My naive guess would be that Org expects these to somehow coexist peacefully.  You should also presumably be able to change any such bindings, if they really are incompatible (or if you prefer other keys).

Comment: I'm using cygwin and GNU Emacs 23.1.1. And I tried more to find out that the real key-binding to clock in and out is C-c C-x C-i and C-c C-x C-o.
The 'messed up' situation may due to my 'messed up' typing. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard key bindings for `org-clock-in/out` are `C-C C-x C-i` and `C-c C-x-C-o` respectively.

The keybindings do not overlap (although they are similar).

If they overlap when you launch Emacs, please check your `~/.emacs`/`~/.emacs.d/init.el` to ensure you haven't changed the bindings.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's my mistake. I used the wrong keybindings and sometimes happen to type it 'right'. And so I got confused. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know that ordered properties are, but I am using the clocking feature.
I don't like multi-key chords so I'm using `org-speed-commands-user` for this purpose:

```
(setq org-speed-commands-user 
      '(("i" . org-clock-in)
        ("o" . org-clock-out)))
```

Now to clock into a heading, I move to its beginning with <kbd>C-a</kbd>.
This is where org speed commands come in effect: any single letter or digit can
be bound to a command.

And I use this code to quickly get to a position where org speed commands
become active:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-a")
              (lambda()(interactive)
                (if (looking-at "^[^*]")
                    (re-search-backward "^*")
                  (org-beginning-of-line))))
```

Also, don't forget that you can clock in/out from the agenda with <kbd>I</kbd>/<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: The following speed commands already exist...
I   org-clock-in
O   org-clock-out; no need to define user ones.

Comment: No need indeed. Except for the convenience of not having to touch the Shift key.